# What SSIS task can be used to download files from an HTTPS URL?

Tags: file, url, https, ssis, download

I'm rathernew to SSIS and need some help creating an SSIS package that will connect to an HTTPS URL and download daily files with a naming convention like 2012-04-09.csv, 2012-04-08.csv and so on.  Any suggestions on how to do this using a Web Service, XML, FTP or any other task would be much appreciated.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The stock HTTP Connection Manager can also be used to accomplish this task.  Add an HTTP Connection Manager to your project, and set the "Server URL" property to the URL from which you wish to download.

This can easily be used in a Script Task to download a file, and you can set the "Server URL" property in an Expression in order to take advantage of variables and Control Flow containers to make this dynamic.

[SQLIS.com - Downloading a file over HTTP the SSIS way](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your best bet would be to use a custom script component to create your own.

This link shows you how to do it: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.pt/2011/05/download-source-file-from-website-with.html